# Regularity - mean curvature equation

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, regularity, curvature

In my research I arrived at the following equation:
$$ \int_B \frac{\nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi}{ \sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}}=\int_B f \varphi, (*)$$
for every $\varphi \in C^1(B)$,
which is a weak form of the mean curvature equation. (Indeed, if $u$ is $C^2$ then we can integrate by parts and get that the curvature of the graph determined by $u$ is $f$.) I kept searching for some regularity results which apply to my setting, but failed to find something which works.

In my context I know that $(*)$ is satisfied, where $B$ is a $d$-dimensional ball, $u$ is of class $C^{1,\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and that $f \in C^\beta$ with $\beta \in (0,1)$.

> My question is: is there any chance of obtaining that $u$ is $C^{1,1}$ or $C^2$ from these assumptions? Are there any standard references to this type of results?

Answer (score 1):

This question is solved in the PhD thesis of Nicolas Landais: *Problèmes de régularité en optimisation de forme.* You can read the thesis [here](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiIiKOB59TLAhVDcBoKHYw-CSIQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftel.archives-ouvertes.fr%2Ftel-00487930%2Fdocument&usg=AFQjCNHN6zcrU9MUmBMcHbTv-jRoy9zEvA&sig2=B6Qiyvt_6bvB9_XTfnDiZw). The result is presented in Chapter 6. The conclusion is that with the given hypotheses the function $u$ is $C^{2,\alpha}(B)$. Nicolas Landais also has two publications which are related to this subject.

The proof uses some results from [the book](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKpuuAqNXLAhXGnBoKHWIQASIQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Ffr%2Fbook%2F9783540411604&usg=AFQjCNFBnwmoaPm2uW0IjexUe8OTm7iRSw&sig2=mzxQOZy3ZVdPqQy6u3hvjA&bvm=bv.117218890,d.d2s) of Gilbarg and Trudinger.